# Node.js chat client on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, tcpsocket

I have a node.js chat server where I developed an iOS client, now I would like to develop another client usable on browser.
I don't want use socket.io or similiar, only pure tcp socket.
This is the code of server:

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');
//var sys = require('sys');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

// Put this new client in the list
clients.push(socket);

// Send a nice welcome message and announce
socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\n", socket);

socket.write(tools.foo);

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function (data) {
broadcast(socket.name + " >> " + data+"\n", socket);
});

// Remove the client from the list when it leaves
socket.on('end', function () {
clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
});

// Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {
clients.forEach(function (client) {
  // Don't want to send it to sender
  if (client === sender) return;
  client.write(message);
});
// Log it to the server output too
process.stdout.write(message)
} 

}).listen(5100,"192.168.1.8");

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 5100\n");
```

What can I use to develop it? I hope with javascript.
Excuse me but I'm newbie of web programming.

Comment: Browsers cannot do raw sockets.  You need to use WebSockets.  If you don't want to use Socket.io, feel free to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Is this question related to your previous? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528970/socket-io-web-client-not-working Your previous one seems to have a little more content than this one.

Comment: I start to work immediately! eheheheh
Thanks for the explanation ;)